Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint
I have this error in my ASP.NET Core MVC logs:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[17]
      Exception occurred while processing message.
      Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
       ---> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectProtocolException: Message contains error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'error_description is null', error_uri: 'error_uri is null'.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RedeemAuthorizationCodeAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage tokenEndpointRequest)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)


My bug using nginx http post reverse proxy to http get how to fix.
Log on the server:
2024-08-01 11:15:36.368 +07:00 [WARNING] [IdentityServer4.Endpoints.TokenEndpoint] [TraceId: fbb5c80f00e9299a7d152e7c1958bea3] [SpanId: cd1c63825efd3d96] [ParentId: c7d1e7e4bab9425c] [MachineName: 172baa574fcf] [ProcessId: 1] Invalid HTTP request for token endpoint
2024-08-01 11:15:36.368 +07:00 [INFORMATION] [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics] [TraceId: fbb5c80f00e9299a7d152e7c1958bea3] [SpanId: cd1c63825efd3d96] [ParentId: c7d1e7e4bab9425c] [MachineName: 172baa574fcf] [ProcessId: 1] Request finished HTTP/1.1 GET http://*.com/connect/token - 400 null application/json; charset=UTF-8 0.7092ms

My config for nginx:
server {
    server_name *.com;

    error_page 497 https://$host$request_uri;
    client_body_buffer_size 32k;
    client_header_buffer_size 8k;
    large_client_header_buffers 8 64k;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        proxy_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/*.com_access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/*.com_error.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/abc.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    server_name *.com;

    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri; # managed by Certbot
}

Note: *.com not my domain I replaced
Fix help me please :(((
I have tried:
public static IServiceCollection AddAuthenticationConfig(this IServiceCollection services,
            IdentityOption identityOption)
{
    // JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
    services.Configure<ForwardedHeadersOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto;
                options.KnownNetworks.Clear();
                options.KnownProxies.Clear();
            });
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityOption.OidcAuthenticationScheme;

                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultForbidScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    options => { options.Cookie.Name = identityOption.IdentityAdminCookieName; })
                .AddOpenIdConnect(IdentityOption.OidcAuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = identityOption.IdentityServerBaseUrl;
                    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = identityOption.RequireHttpsMetadata;
                    options.ClientId = identityOption.ClientId;
                    options.ClientSecret = identityOption.ClientSecret;
                    options.ResponseType = identityOption.OidcResponseType;
                    options.Scope.Clear();

                    foreach (var scope in identityOption.Scopes) 
                         options.Scope.Add(scope);
                    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(identityOption.TokenValidationClaimRole,
                        identityOption.TokenValidationClaimRole, identityOption.TokenValidationClaimRole);
                    options.SaveTokens = true;
                    options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        NameClaimType = identityOption.TokenValidationClaimName,
                        RoleClaimType = identityOption.TokenValidationClaimRole
                    };
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnMessageReceived = context => OnMessageReceived(context, identityOption),
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context => OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(context, identityOption)
                    };
                    options.BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler
                    {
                        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
                            HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator
                    };
                });
    services.AddHsts(options =>
            {
                options.Preload = true;
                options.IncludeSubDomains = true;
                options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365);
            });

    return services;
}

private static Task OnMessageReceived(MessageReceivedContext context, IdentityOption identityOption)
{
    context.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
    context.Properties.ExpiresUtc = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddHours(identityOption.IdentityAdminCookieExpiresUtcHours));

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

private static Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context, IdentityOption identityOption)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(identityOption.IdentityAdminRedirectUri))
        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = identityOption.IdentityAdminRedirectUri;

    return Task.CompletedTask;
}

appsettings.json:
{
  "IdentityConfiguration": {
    "IdentityAdminRedirectUri": "https://localhost:7101/signin-oidc",
    "IdentityServerBaseUrl": "https://*.com",
    "IdentityAdminCookieName": "IdentityServerAdmin",
    "IdentityAdminCookieExpiresUtcHours": 12,
    "RequireHttpsMetadata": false,
    "TokenValidationClaimName": "name",
    "TokenValidationClaimRole": "role",
    "ClientId": "abc",
    "ClientSecret": "abc",
    "OidcResponseType": "code",
    "Scopes": [
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "email",
      "roles"
    ]
  }
}

I've converted the content to markdown format. The markdown version includes proper headings, code blocks with language specification, and image links. Is there anything else you'd like me to do with this markdown content?

Is it not because you're making a GET rather than a POST?

I'm really not sure why everything works fine when I integrate with a web framework using REST API calls, but when I integrate it on ASP.NET MVC using the OpenID Connect library, it results in an error

Yes, It seems like the NGINX configuration has converted my POST method into GET

@ProgrammingLlama how to fix ??

I don't think the NGINX will convert Post to Get, I suggest you could use network capture or else to see what has happened.
